# Can't open .jar files with double click

Tags: java, windows, jar

I've been learning java recently and I need to be able to open .jar files, but outside of cmd, I can't anymore. .jar files just don't have an icon (it does, it's just a white square) and when i double click it, it prompts me to open as. I've followed a few things and opened it with java.exe, but it just closed down instantly.

Comment: You should unzip it to see .class files. You should run with `java -jar myjar.jar` command from command line.

Comment: @N.Dogac how is that helping in this scenario?

Comment: @f1sh He/she is trying to open jar files. So unzipping it will open it.

Comment: @N.Dogac if he/she opened the jar files with java before, unzipping is not what he/she wants. The purpose it running the (runnable) jar file, his OS simply does not have the association to the `java -jar` command anymore.

Comment: @Danghet what exactly do you want to happen when you double click them? open them as an archive or run the jar file?

Answer (score 1):

```
To open a jar file in Windows, you must have the Java Runtime Environment installed. Alternatively, you can use decompression software, such as an unzip utility, to view the files in the jar archive.

If the jar file opens using an archive program, such as WinRAR or 7-Zip, and you want Java to open it instead, follow the instructions below. (The jar file must contain executable Java code for these steps to work.)

1-Right-click the file and select Open With.
2-In the Open With window, click the Browse button to open the File Explorer window.
3-You need to find the Java executable file (java.exe file) on your computer hard drive. It is often located in the "Program Files\Java" or "Program Files (x86)\Java" folder, within a possible subfolder below the Java folder. Once you find the file, select it and click OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to open the jar file, you can use a file decompressor like [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to see the contents that are inside.